# WHMCS server integration with WHM

Tags: whm, whmcs

I m trying to integrate WHM server with WHMCS server configuration as per its documents. https://docs.whmcs.com/Servers but the problem is its not configuring  properly. When ever i try to log into whm from WHMCS its being redirected to WHMCS login page.

I test server connection with ssl option checked then it shows successful connection without ssl its showing error.

and when ever i anyone place order it throw an error showing the product is not found in the server whereas the product is there in WHM server. i have double checked it.
So guyz any hint or suggestion where i could be wrong.

**Parameters i have used:**

Name    WHM/cPanel

Hostname : My WHM server link

IP Address : WHM server IP address

Primary Nameserver : WHM name server from its configuration

Secondary Nameserver: WHM name server from its configuration

**Server Detail**

Type cPanel

Username : username of WHM

password : password of whm

api token : manage api token from whm

Secure ssl enable

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing specifically from where you are attempting to login to the WHM server in WHMCS (WHMCS Connect, configservers.php page, client area, etc), I would suggest replacing

IP Address : WHM server IP address

with

IP Address : WHM Hostname

This could only work with properly configured SSL hostname.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with WHM Re seller provider. But the problem has been resolved for now. Ty for your support :))